# Find user by email

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, jtable

How can I look up a user by email? I thought that `JTable::load` would do it, but it returns a weird data shape:

```
$user = JTable::getInstance('User', 'JTable', array());
$user->load(array("email" => "someemail@gmail.com"));
print_r(json_encode($user))

            groups": null,
            "id": {
                "email": "someemail@gmail.com"
            },
            "name": "",
            "username": "",
            "email": "",
            ...
```

`JTable::load` works like this for Categories, however.

```
$cat = JTable::getInstance('Category', 'JTable', array());
$cat->load(array("title" => "some title"));
```

Do I have to use `JFactory::getDbo()`?

Comment: I assume that you have tested your code using both existing and non-existing email addresses? I would kind of expect to see a bunch of null and empty values if I searched for a non-existent user.

Comment: yes, I've tested with both. They both return the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Joomla\CMS\Table\User::load()` can only load rows by user ID. Use database query to get user ID by email and pass it to table's `load()` method:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->quoteName('id'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('email') . ' = ' . $db->quote($email));
$db->setQuery($query);

if ($id = $db->loadResult())
{
    $user = JTable::getInstance('User', 'JTable', array());
    $user->load($id);
}
else
{
    // User with specified $email not found.
}
```

If you don't intend changing user data in the table, you can use `JFactory::getUser()` instead:

```
if ($id = $db->loadResult())
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser($id);
}
```

Comment: ...but can this be done with `JTable::load`?

Comment: Yes, exactly same way. Get user ID and pass it to `JTable::load()`.

Comment: I mean, can it be done without the `JFactory::getDbo()`?  This is the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. Unlike `Joomla\CMS\Table::load()`, `Joomla\CMS\Table\User::load()` can only load row by user ID instead of multiple column/value pairs.

Comment: This is relevant to the question and your answer.  Please edit this knowledge into your answer to make it more complete (upvote worthy).  ...I don't know if what you are saying is true -- just trying to improve page content and put the full story in one place.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Sharky I'm not sure this is using `Joomla\CMS\Table\User::load`, which does only seem to permit primary ids. See my added, working example with Categories.  `Joomla\CMS\Table\Category::load` also only works with primary ids, but I don't think that's the model returned by `JTable::getInstance`. Seems unlikely that we'd actually be working with `Joomla\CMS\Table\User`

Comment: Classes are correct. This works with Category because it does not override `Joomla\CMS\Table::load()` method which accepts both primary keys and column/value pairs (i.e. you can use both `$cat->load($id)` and `$cat->load(array('id' => $id))`). See source code https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/7b73d5f230fd6506cbc10e6cf84de532c3798692/libraries/src/Table/Table.php#L663-L727.